# Calling a class function in blade view laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a CartController with the following function:

```
  public function getTotalCartPrice()
    {
        $totalCartPrice = 1;
        
        return $totalCartPrice;
    }
```

Cart.blade.php

```
<h3 class="cartTotal">Cart total: {{ Cart::getTotalCartPrice }} </h3>
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('/cart', CartController::class);
```

Using this does not seem to display the total cart price and I get an error saying class "Cart" not found. I have attempted to change my route to this:

```
Route::get('/cartPrice', [CartController::class, 'getTotalCartPrice'])->name('getTotalCartPrice');
```

and then inside my blade view:

```
<h3 class="cartTotal">Cart total: {{ route('getTotalCartPrice') }} </h3>
```

But I just get an output on the website:

```
Cart total: http://localhost/cartPrice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to help you.

To fix this error, you should add **static** keyword to function **getTotalCartPrice** in CartController. So it will be :

```
public static function getTotalCartPrice()
{
    $totalCartPrice = 1;
    
    return $totalCartPrice;
}
```

After that, in your view (blade) you should add Cart class in the top of the code. In this case I assume that your Cart controller class name is Cart, so the example is :

```
@php
    use App\Http\Controllers\Cart;
@endphp
// the rest of blade code
```

After that, you have to add **()** when you call the function from your blade

```
<h3 class="cartTotal">Cart total: {{ Cart::getTotalCartPrice() }} </h3>
```

After that, the total cart must be shown.